# My nested for loop times out when searching for 2 numbers in an array that add up to a sum value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to find a better/faster algorithm that doesn't timeout when I try to find any 2 numbers in an array of numbers that add up to a sum(ex. s).  I need to return the pair of numbers that adds up to sum(s) which also have the indices that appear the earliest(there maybe many other pairs).  Here is my nested for loop approach.

```
function sum(ints, s){
  let pusher = [];
  let count = 1000;
  for(let i = 0; i < ints.length; i++){
      for(let j = i+1; j < ints.length; j++){
        if(ints[i] + ints[j] === s){
          if(j < count){
            pusher = [ints[i],ints[j]];
            count = j;  
          }
        } 
    }
  }
  return pusher.length > 0 ? pusher : undefined ;
}
```

Comment: timeout? can you show an example of arguments to this function that "time out" - you must be passing a HUGE array as `ints` if this causes a browser to stop the code

Comment: This works with simple smaller arrays like
 let array = [1, 9, 15, 2, 4, 7, 5]
 let s = 6;
Should return [2,4] not [1,5].

Comment: so, the algorithm is wrong, but your question is regarding "timeout" not accuracy - anyway ... 1+5 = 6 ... and that will be the first result found

Comment: Not really, just super long array's.  I think the time limit is under 12 seconds.  I guess I am seeing if someone can help me make a quicker algorithm.  No because index of j would be 6 and for 2 and 4 j's index would be 4.

Comment: it actually DOES return `[2,4]` for your example - still, nothing to do with your question

Comment: how long are the arrays?

Comment: up to 10,000,000 elements.  I know I said it works on smaller arrays.  Im trying to find a faster solution than nested for loops.... Do you know of a faster way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the computational complexity from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)`, create a Setinstead. When iterating over a number, check if the set has the value `sum - num` - if it does, return that pair as the result. Otherwise, put the number into the Set:

Or you could use a Set

```js
function sum(ints, sum) {
  const set = new Set();
  for (const num of ints) {
    const otherNum = sum - num;
    if (set.has(otherNum)) {
      return [num, otherNum];
    } else {
      set.add(num);
    }
  }
}
console.log(sum([3, 4, 99, -2, 55, 66, -3], 1));
console.log(sum([1, 9, 15, 2, 4, 7, 5], 6));
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to learn more about sets, but this seems to pass the time out problem!